# How to differentiate logarithms with the ti 89?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, calculator

I'm having difficulty entering the the correct syntax into my ti 89 calculator to differentiate logarithms.

So far this is what I cam up with for f'(X) = log6(x^2-3x-4)
1. f3 click differentiate
2. catalog click log(
3. enter syntax log(6)(x^2-3x-4),x)

correct answer is (2x-3)/(x^2-3x-4)*(ln6)

I do not return that answer with my syntax please help! And thank you

Answer (score 1):

On the TI-89 Titanium, you could take the base $b$ log of $x$ by entering `log(x,b)` into the calculator.

In this case, type in `d(log(x^2-3x-4,6),x)` and you should get the right answer. The *d* needs to be the special character differentiation *d* (see [this page](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/68k:d), or the calculator's manual, for more details). Everything else can be typed in directly from the keyboard: you *can*, if you like, type in `log(` by pressing [♦] [7], but it's also okay to just type it in letter by letter.

On the regular TI-89, `log(x,b)` is not allowed, and there's no feature that allows logs to arbitrary bases, but you can replace it by `ln(x)/ln(b)`. So you'd type in `d(ln(x^2-3x-4)/ln(6),x)` and otherwise proceed as above. (Using `log(x)/log(b)` would also work.)

Comment: Tried it and I receive the error message "too many arguments."

Comment: Sorry; it works on the TI-89 Titanium, but I just checked the older manual online and it's a feature that the older calculator didn't have; I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes it worked for me with one exception.  I needed to add another parenthesis to d(ln(x^2-3x-4)/ln(6)),x)!